# Sometimes loss of data when getting result from a Async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-networking

Consider the async task below:

```
protected class FetchArticlesAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Category, Integer, HashMap<String, Object>> 
{
    private final String TAG = FetchArticlesAsyncTask.class.getSimpleName();
    private HashMap<String, Object> data;
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(Category... categories) 
    {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        Articles articles = ... // Get sth from HTTP
        result.put("articles", articles);
        Log.d(TAG, "result = " + result); // Print out sth which is OK

        return result;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> result) 
    {
        notifyAsyncTask(FetchArticlesAsyncTask.class, result, this.data);                
    }


..
```

And in my caller, I have

```
protected void notifyFetchArticlesAsyncTask(Class<?> c, Object result, Object input)
{
    HashMap<String, Object> data = (HashMap<String, Object>) result;
    Log.d(TAG, "result = " + result); // result is SOMETIMES empty map? WHY
}
```

The issue is only sometimes I will get empty map in `notifyFetchArticlesAsyncTask`, but the result can be printed successfully in  `doInBackground`.

Why just sometimes not working?

Comment: Make sure you create result HashMap instance inside doInBackground(). This is not visible from your code. Generally AsyncTask works very reliable and the issue you have can only happen, if your code cleans result HashMap or creates a new instance of it, in case it's declared as a class field.

Comment: @beworker, I added back the missing code. Thanks for your comment

Comment: You call notifyAsyncTask() but showed us notifyFetchArticlesAsyncTask() code. What does happen in between these calls?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like this

```
protected Object doInBackground(Category... categories) 
{
    Articles articles = ... // Get sth from HTTP
    return articles;
}
protected void onPostExecute(Object articles) 
{
     HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
     result.put("articles", articles);
     Log.d(TAG, "result = " + result); // Print out sth which is OK

    notifyAsyncTask(FetchArticlesAsyncTask.class, result, this.data);                
}
```